# How can I use a type as a function parameter in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, types

Visual Studio reports that 
"'PhoenixEngineTypes.BehaviorTypes' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'".

```
public void AddBehavior(BehaviorTypes type)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(BehaviorTypes, type))
        {
        switch (type)
        {
            case BehaviorTypes.render:
            break;   
        }
    }
```

The definition of BehaviorTypes is:

```
[Flags]
enum BehaviorTypes : uint
{
    default_behavior = 1 >> 0,
    select = 1 >> 1,
    render = 1 >> 2,
    animate = 1 >> 3,
    navigate = 1 >> 4,
    rotate = 1 >> 5,
    group = 1 >> 6,
    scale = 1 >> 7,
    collide = 1 >> 8,
    kill = 1 >> 9,
    attack = 1 >> 10,
    audio = 1 >> 11,
    all = UInt32.MaxValue
}
```

And finally:

```
public static bool IsDefined(Type enumType, object value);
```

Why can't I do this?
I tried using `typeof(type)` and it compiles, but why waste a function call when the type is not variable? Shouldn't I be able to use the token directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `IsDefined` as follows

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(BehaviorTypes), type)
```

as it expects an instance of `Type` as input. `BehaviorTypes` is not an instance of `Type`, but you can get the corresponding `Type` instance for a type by using `typeof`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx

Comment: So why Does the VS error say that BehaviorTypes is a type but is used like a variable? Confusing.

Comment: `BehaviorTypes` is a type. It's an enum. The method expects a reference to an instance of the class `Type`, or a variable if you will (it's admittedly a little confusing talking about types in general and the class `Type`). You could do `var t = typeof(BehaviorTypes)` and pass `t` instead if that makes it clearer.